# Loop through array of objects, hide duplicates, and show number of items?

Tags: vuejs2

i am not the best at JavaScript, but have a complex challenge that I am having trouble figuring out.

I need to accomplish the following 3 things:

1. **Loop through an array of objects and display the office names**
2. **Show the number of unresolved tickets/issues for each office**
3. **I will then use the office id as a param for vue router later ...but we can ignore that one for now as my focus is just on items 1 and 2.**

My [**JSFIDDLE demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/f9q7L8y5/):

> Here's my HTML template:

```
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Office</th>
    <th>Number of Unresolved Issues</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr v-for="office in unresolvedIssues" :key="office.issueId">
    <td>{{office.office}}</td>
    <td></td> 
  </tr>
</table>
  </div>
</div>
```

> And then my Vue code:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    unresolvedIssues: [
      { issueId: "12345", status: 7, office: "blue" },
            { issueId: "56781", status: 7, office: "orange" },
      { issueId: "23145", status: 7, office: "red" },
      { issueId: "12311", status: 7, office: "blue" },
      { issueId: "33144", status: 7, office: "orange" },
      { issueId: "33244", status: 7, office: "yellow" },
    ],
    offices: [
        { office: 'blue', office_id: 3 },
      { office: 'red', office_id: 1 },
      { office: 'orange', office_id: 2 },
      { office: 'yellow', office_id: 4 },
    ]

  },
  methods: {
  }
})
```

In my above code, the v-for gives me the offices, but some offices are listed twice (e.g, "blue" office). How would I filter this array and only show each office once? I thought of trying .reduce() but my attempt did not work. Thanks for anyone that can help!

Comment: Check out some great es6 methods to eliminate duplicates:
https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-remove-array-duplicates-in-es6-5daa8789641c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track with `reduce`. And since you're using Vue, it's best to put it into a computed property as well:

```
computed: {
  unresolvedIssuesGroupedByOffice() {
    return this.unresolvedIssues.reduce((groups, issue) => {
      let office = groups[issue.office] || []
      office.push(issue)
      groups[issue.office] = office
      return groups
    }, {})
  }
}
```

Your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7g8zL2nw/